# Restfull Controller test leasds to error 404 istead of 200. Not a typo mistake

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, junit

I am writing a MVC application in java. Currently I am trying to write a test for my RESTfullController. The problem arises when I am trying to the get() trying to work. I get back a 404 instead of a 202. I have invested a lot of time in order to figure this out but could not. I will post my controller and the ControllerTest here

```
package com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.web;

import com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.config.WebAppInitializer;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;


/**
 * User: nikhil.thakur
 * Date: 12/18/13
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppInitializer.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RestfullControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
      mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/videos/"))
              .andExpect(status().isOk());
 //             .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(4)));

    }

 }
```

The controller that I am trying to test is 
package com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.web;

```
   import com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.entity.Video;
    import com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.services.LookupService;
    import com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.services.VideoService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.util.Assert;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class RESTfulController {

        @Autowired
        LookupService lookupService;

        @Autowired
        VideoService videoService;

        @RequestMapping("keywords")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findAllKeywords() {
            return lookupService.findAllKeywords().toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping("subjects")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findAllSubjects() {
            return lookupService.findAllSubjects().toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping("presenters")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findAllPresenters() {
            return lookupService.findAllPresenters().toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findAllVideos() {
             return videoService.findAll().toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findVideosByKeywordsIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findVideosByKeywordsIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "keywords") String keywords) {

            return videoService.findVideosByKeywordsIdIn(getListOfIntegers(keywords)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findByPresentersIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findByPresentersIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "presenters") String presenters) {

            return videoService.findByPresentersIdIn(getListOfIntegers(presenters)).toString();

        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findBySubjectsIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findBySubjectsIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "subjects") String subjects) {

            return videoService.findBySubjectsIdIn(getListOfIntegers(subjects)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdInAndSubjectsIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdInAndSubjectsIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "keywords") String keywords, @RequestParam(value = "presenters") String presenters, @RequestParam(value = "subjects") String subjects) {


            return videoService.findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdInAndSubjectsIdIn(getListOfIntegers(keywords), getListOfIntegers(presenters), getListOfIntegers(subjects)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "keywords") String keywords, @RequestParam(value = "presenters") String presenters) {

            return videoService.findByKeywordsIdInAndPresentersIdIn(getListOfIntegers(keywords),getListOfIntegers(presenters)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findBySubjectsIdInAndPresentersIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findBySubjectsIdInAndPresentersIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "subjects") String subjects, @RequestParam(value = "presenters") String presenters) {

            return videoService.findBySubjectsIdInAndPresentersIdIn(getListOfIntegers(subjects),getListOfIntegers(presenters)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "videos/findBySubjectsIdInAndKeywordsIdIn", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String findBySubjectsIdInAndKeywordsIdIn(@RequestParam(value = "subjects") String subjects, @RequestParam(value = "keywords") String keywords) {

            return videoService.findBySubjectsIdInAndKeywordsIdIn(getListOfIntegers(subjects),getListOfIntegers(keywords)).toString();

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "video/{videoId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String readVideo(@PathVariable Integer videoId, Model model) {
            Assert.notNull(videoId);
            return videoService.findOne(videoId).toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "video/{videoId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String updateVideo(@RequestBody Video video, @PathVariable Integer videoId, Model model) {
            Assert.notNull(video);
            return videoService.save(video).toString();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "video", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String createVideo(@RequestBody Video video, Model model) {
            Assert.notNull(video);
            return videoService.save(video).toString();
        }

        private List<Integer> getListOfIntegers(String keywords) {
            List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (String id : keywords.split(";") ) {
                new Integer(id);
            }
            return ids;
        }
    }
```

---

Note that when i access "http://:8080/rest/videos/ " then I do see an output on the page.

My WebAppInitializer looks like this.

```
package com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

/**
 * @author nikhil.thakur
 * @since 12/12/13
 */
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static final String CONFIG_PACKAGE = "com.bestbuy.supportspace.videolibrary.config";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan(CONFIG_PACKAGE);

        addHttpMethodFilter(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/rest/*");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
    }

    private void addHttpMethodFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic httpMethodFilter = servletContext.addFilter("HttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
        httpMethodFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/videos/"))
```

I'm pretty sure that in your case "rest" is the name / url part of the application. It's irrelevant for the test. Just use "/videos".

Comment: My WebAppInitializer looks like this.

Comment: So I thought just using the /videos would run it, but it does not. How I am trying to figure out this problem is to debug the test method and see where is what is the prefix for this mapping. I am not being able to find that too

Comment: @NikhilThakur I don't think the servlet mapping ("/rest/*") is relevant here, but I'm not sure. Anyway, I just noticed the there is actually no controller method mapped to "videos/" , only to "videos", without a trailing slash.

Comment: it doesnt make a difference. I tried making it work with /videos, but still i would only get a 404

Comment: @NikhilThakur Can you confirm that your methods get mapped after all during the unit test? Have you checked the output of the console?